# Where do I put (and how do I read) my own custom XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml

Sorry, this seems like such an obvious question, but I just can't find an answer in the docs...

I have my own XML doc (not Android related) that I need to pull and parse at run time.

Where do I store it and what's the best way to retrieve it?  Do I just read it as a text document into an XML parser? Or does Android come prepared to hand me back a parsed XML object from a well formed xml?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a `xml` folder in `res`.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel you should be able to access your file with `R.xml.file_name` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.xml.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in assets folder of your project.

For parsing you can use `openXmlResourceParser(filename)` method of `AssetsManager` class

```
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getAssets().openXmlResourceParser (String fileName);
```

Comment: check this tutorial for accessing files from `raw` and `assets` folders : http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to put your xml in assets folder and read xml from assets.

[Read xml from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893364/xml-pull-parser-assets-xml/4690168#4690168)